optimize sql query - set value to variable to use on other query
I'm particularly interested in using of variables VAR_trip_time and VAR_cmimi from the first query
and then reuse those values in other queries below.
i tried this
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `RIDE_stop`(IN `param_skuID` INT, IN `param_cmimi_per_1_sekond` DECIMAL(6,4), IN `pram_userID` INT)

BEGIN
DECLARE VAR_trip_time INT;
DECLARE VAR_cmimi INT;

UPDATE sku_rides R
INNER JOIN sku S ON S.skuID = R.skuID
SET R.endTime = NOW(),
   
    R.zona = S.zona,
    VAR_trip_time = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, R.startTime, NOW()),
    VAR_cmimi = ROUND(VAR_trip_time * param_cmimi_per_1_sekond),
    R.cmimi = VAR_cmimi,
    R.trip_time = VAR_trip_time
WHERE R.skuID = param_skuID AND R.userID = param_userID AND R.endTime IS NULL 
ORDER BY R.rideID DESC 
LIMIT 1;

UPDATE users SET kredit = kredit - VAR_cmimi WHERE userID = param_userID;

UPDATE sku SET userID = NULL WHERE skuID = param_skuID;

END


check code that i tried:   VAR_trip_time   and VAR_cmimi  need to be something like this, this is what i need  but this syntax i think dont work. what i try to do is set the value to those VAR_...

WHERE skuID = skuID AND userID = userID doesn't do any filtering, it returns all rows. But you can only assign a single value to a variable.

userID and skuID  are Parameters

You're still comparing them witht themselves. You need to use tablename.skuID = skuID to compare the row value with the parameter. It's generally best to avoid using variables with the same name as columns.

let me edit the post

Your query is incorrect. Leftpart names in SET .. VAR_trip_time = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, R.startTime, NOW()), VAR_cmimi = ROUND(VAR_trip_time * param_cmimi_per_1_sekond) .. clause of UPDATE statement are unconditionally treated as a column names, hence you will receive "unknown column" error.

If your UPDATE is deterministic (i.e your ORDER BY provides the rows uniqueness) then select the row to be updated with separate SELECT statement and store needed values into the variables, then use them in the rightpart expressions.
